# how to do a printer-like text field using javascript OOP

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a printer-like text field which could show the letter one by one. I could realize it just use a function and load it as simple like:

html---

```
<div id="myTypingText"></div>
```

js---

```
 <script>
    var myString = "Place your string data here, and as much as you like.";
    var myArray = myString.split("");
    var loopTimer;
    function frameLooper() {
        if(myArray.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
        } else {
            clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
                    return false;
        }
        loopTimer = setTimeout('frameLooper()',70);
    }
    frameLooper();
    </script>
```

But I want to do more advanced, I want to let the user to change the speed and change the text, so I wrote the following one but it went wrong, why? help me .thx.

html----

```
 <div id="myTypingText"></div>
    <p>Enter the tempo:</p><input type="text" id="tempo" value="70">
    <p>Enter the Text:<p><input type="text" id="text" value="abcdefghijklmn">
    <button onclick="begin()">Begin</button>
```

js----

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function Printer(){
        this.myString = document.getElementById("text").value;
        this.myArray = this.myString.split("");
        this.tempo = document.getElementById("tempo").value;
        this.len = this.myArray.length;
        this.loop = function (){
            if(this.len > 0 ){
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += this.myArray.shift();
            }

        }
    }

    function begin(){
        var test = new Printer();
        setInterval(test.loop,test.tempo);
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an anonymous function in the interval if you want the `loop` function to be executed in the context of the `Printer` object. Also you need to check the length of the array each time as the `len` property won't be updated when the array is shifted.

```
function Printer() {
    this.myString = document.getElementById("text").value;
    this.myArray = this.myString.split("");
    this.tempo = document.getElementById("tempo").value;
    this.loop = function () {
        if (this.myArray.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += this.myArray.shift();
        }

    }
}

function begin() {
    var test = new Printer();
    setInterval(function () {
        test.loop()
    }, test.tempo);
}
```

See the **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/hS7Zh/)**

Comment: so...use the anonymous function function(){test.loop()},then the this.myArray could be got from Printer,right? so the anonymous function could request any required variables even within the other function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. Your fundamental problem was with using the this keyword. You have to remember that when you enter another function scope, the this keyword changes. You'll notice here that I cache or save 'this' to equal that, then use that new 'that' value in the function. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2viipymQLnrBx67gsmDB?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="myTypingText"></div>
    <p>Enter the tempo:</p><input type="text" id="tempo" value="70">
    <p>Enter the Text:<p><input type="text" id="text" value="abcdefghijklmn">
    <button onclick="begin()">Begin</button>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    function Printer(){
        this.myString = document.getElementById("text").value;
        this.myArray = this.myString.split("");
        this.tempo = document.getElementById("tempo").value;
        this.len = this.myArray.length;
        var that = this;
        this.loop = function (){
            if(that.myArray.length !== 0 ){
                document.getElementById("myTypingText").innerHTML += that.myArray.shift();
            }

        }
    }

    function begin(){
        var test = new Printer();
        setInterval(test.loop,test.tempo);
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```